# CDN blocked by ISP solution?

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, cdn

What is the best option for me to access a website whose CDN has been blocked by my ISP . Data is important to me , so I'm a bit hesitant to use a VPN . Also , I've tried flushing my DNS cache and using Google's DNS . I cant seem to access this website . All the methods mentioned have failed . I'm on mac . 
[image]

Comment: Have you talked to your ISP? This seems like a strange URL to block - although Indian ISPs have some strange blocking rules ...

Comment: Can you do a simple dig to resolve the domain name? What are the results? Any change if you connect directly via IP to the website in question?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error for `https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/`

Flushing the DNS Cache worked for me.

If you want to see the existing records before flushing run CMD and:

```
ipconfig /displaydns  > tmp.txt && notepad.exe tmp.txt
```

(Credit: https://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=6247)

To flush the DNS run CMD and:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```